# Android app, keep sending request even if app is killed

Tags: android

I want to create an android app that sends a get request once a minute to a server. Based on the response I would like to set an alarm on my phone. I need the request to keep being sent after the app is closed and killed. Could someone please help me with a list of steps/tutorials that I could follow in order to achieve this? also, I need to use java code

Comment: You have to use foreground service for this.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides `WorkManager` APIs  to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts.

References:

[Schedule Tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[Guide to background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

Comment: Is there a way to also schedule an alarm from a worker?

Comment: You can use AlarmManager for scheduling repeating alarms. Here is the reference link https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms. This link also provides the code snippet.

Comment: By alarm I mean the actual alarm of a phone, I have tried but it only works when the app is in foregroud